# Docker run maps volumes with user "nobody" of "nogroup"

Tags: docker

So far I have not had this problem. I am running a container image in a remote workstation. Different than normal, this workstation is not connected to the internet and I had to initiate the docker deamon manually. (for reference)

After this to run the container I tried to do

```
docker run -it -t --rm --gpus all --env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES -v "/mnt/disco/projects/ThisProject/:/home/ThisProject/" -w "/
home/ThisProject/"  container_image:latest /bin/bash
```

When I do this I got into the container on folder `/home/ThisProject` with root user but I cannot ls here. I do `cd ..` and `ls -l` and I can see that the ThisProject folder has this

```
drwxrws--- 7 nobody nogroup 4096 Jul 21 07:30 ThisProject
```

As you can see the owner is "nobody"

What can I do to correct this?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I have the same behaviour, with nobody:nobody. Thank you

Comment: Same happens for me on any Raspberry Pi (4B/5/Zero2) with debian bookworm.

Comment: It could be helpful to share which container you are running. Either way, check out this answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563969/358561

Answer (score 6):

When you [mount a volume in Docker using the `-v` option](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), the permissions and ownership of the files inside the container are the same as those on the host machine. However, if Docker cannot map the host user to a user inside the container (or if it is run with a [user namespace remapping](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) feature), it defaults to using an unprivileged user, often `nobody:nogroup`.

```bash
Host System                       Docker Container
+-----------------------+         +-----------------------+
| /mnt/disco/projects/  |         | /home/ThatProject/    |
| ThatProject/          |  ---->  | (owned by nobody)     |
| (owned by your user)  |         |                       |
+-----------------------+         +-----------------------+
```

You might consider:

- **Matching User IDs (UID) and Group IDs (GID)**: You can explicitly set the user and group ID in the container to match those of the host directory. That approach requires you to first find out the UID and GID of the `/mnt/disco/projects/ThatProject/` directory on the host and then use the `--user` flag in your `docker run` command to set the container's user and group ID.

  First, find out the UID and GID on the host (replace `/path/to/your/directory` with the actual path):

  ```bash
  stat -c "%u:%g" /mnt/disco/projects/ThatProject/
  ```

  Then, run your container with the `--user` flag:

  ```bash
  docker run -it --rm --gpus all --env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES --user <UID>:<GID> -v "/mnt/disco/projects/ThatProject/:/home/ThatProject/" -w "/home/ThatProject/" container_image:latest /bin/bash
  ```

  Replace `<UID>` and `<GID>` with the actual values obtained from the `stat` command.
- **Change ownership or permissions on the host**: Another approach is to change the ownership or permissions of the directory on the host to allow the default container user (`nobody` in this case) to access it. That approach can have security implications, so I would not recommend it.
- **Use a dockerfile to create a custom image**: (this is usually what I end up doing) If you frequently run containers with specific volume permissions, consider creating a custom Docker image that sets up a user with the same UID and GID as the host directory. In your Dockerfile, you can add commands to create a user and set the appropriate UID and GID.

```bash
Host System                       Docker Container
+-----------------------+         +-----------------------+
| /mnt/disco/projects/  |         | /home/ThatProject/    |
| ThatProject/          |  ---->  | (matching UID/GID)    |
| (owned by your user)  |         |                       |
+-----------------------+         +-----------------------+
```

I tried fiddling with `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid`, and it can work for one image, but as soon as I have a different image with the same internal user 1000:1000... I cannot map it to a different host user.

Answer (score 1):

This is often seen when the container is running in a user namespace and the mapping of uid/gid's in the container is outside of the uid/gid of the mounted filesystem. User namespaces are used when either enabled explicitly, or implicitly when docker is deployed in a "rootless" configuration. The mapping of uid and gid is seen in the `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` files on the host.

So if the `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` is configured with a line like:

```
user:100000:65536
```

That will map the container user namespace to starting at uid (or gid) 100000, up to 165536. If the file on the host is owned by uid 1000, the kernel will just mark it as inaccessible with a nobody uid/gid.

Fixes for this include not running with a user namespace, making the user namespace overlap with the host user, or changing the uid/gid of the files to be in the container's user namespace.

For changing the user namespace mapping, I've sometimes seen entries like:

```
user:1000:1
user:100000:65535
```

which would map root in the container (uid 0) to uid 1000 on the host, and the rest of the uid/gid mappings would be mapped to 100000-165535 on the host.

And for changing the file ownership, that would look like:

```bash
sudo chown -R 101000:101000 /path/on/host
```

assuming you wanted the files to be owned by uid 1000 in the container and the /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid contained entries like `user:100000:65536`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your context with `docker info`. Had the same issue on Raspberry Pi, changed context to default and now it works: `docker context use default`.